# How can I pass parameters to a Twilio number voice URL with PHP?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

Currently, I making a call using Twilio with their REST API using the Twilio php helper library, I'm dialing the a Twilio number which have a Voice URL setup, in this case, I need to send some parameters to that URL from the REST API call which I can't for the moment, because the URL is set on the Twilio console and I need to sent some user data based on the call, but I haven't seen anything that allows me to do that, in the documentation it's not saying anything about that, it's possible to achieve that?

Thank you beforehand

Comment: Are you trying to pass parameters to your Voice URL on an incoming call? What kind of parameters?

Comment: @philnash Yes, on an incoming call and I'm trying to send the number that I want to dial inside the Voice URL of my Twilio number (I want to dial another number when I receive the call on my Twilio number)

Comment: Could you explain the full use case a bit more? I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I feel there is a better solution out there.

Comment: @philnash it's not a real case, I just wanted to check if this possible with Twilio, checking the capabilities to make sure that sending those params is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can set parameters in the Voice URL in the Twilio dashboard using URL parameters. For example, if you set the URL to be http://example.com/voice?foo=bar then you should be able to extract `bar` with `$_REQUEST['foo']`.

Twilio also sends a number of parameters to your URL with an incoming call, including the number that was dialled (useful if you have multiple incoming numbers), the number dialled from and [many more](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request). You should be able to use the information in the request from Twilio to choose where to dial your call onto. For example, if you are expecting a call from a particular number and you know you want to forward that call onto a different number, you can setup a conditional based on the `From` parameter.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ok, perfect, but if want to have those URL parameters set dynamically instead of putting that on the Twilio Dashboard, it's possible? Thanks.

Comment: You can [update the Voice URL for your number using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-post).

Comment: In the same way can we set parameters for `Request URL` used for inbound SMS ??

Comment: @SameerK Yes you can :)

Comment: @philnash   Can you please let me know how this can be accomplished? I am using PHP and Twilio api to send SMS.

Comment: @SameerK It's exactly the same as I've described for Voice URL parameters above, just update the Message URL instead. Are you trying to do something different? Would it be easier to email me (philnash@twilio.com) instead?

Comment: @philnash, thanks for sharing the email id, i have sent an email to you with details. Please have look and let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters dynamically in your code like this:

```
<?php
$query_string = array(
    'param1' => $param1,
    'param2' => $param2
);
?>

    $call = $twilio_client->account->calls->create(
        '+1' . $outbound_caller_id,
        '+1' . $number_to_call,
        ' http://example.com/voice' . '?' . http_build_query($query_string, '', '&'),
        array(
            'StatusCallback' => ' http://example.com/statuscallbaclurl' . '?' . http_build_query($query_string, '', '&')
        )
    );
```

When using the REST API to create a call you can specify a ULR that will be requested once the call is answered by the dialed party, and as showed above you can pass query string parameters. In addition you can do the same to the **StatusCallback** URL.